# Remove zero Sum Consecutive Nodes from Linked List - How does this code works for test cases like this?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I have a linked list like this as my input `(1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (-3) -> (4) -> NULL` 
And I wish to remove the consecutive nodes which have sum equal to zero i.e., I want my output linked list to be like this: `(1) -> (2) -> (4) -> NULL`

I have already solved this problem using approach of `map` and `array`, and then I came across the code shown below. And this code works perfectly fine for the the above test case and I'm unable to understand how?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeZeroSumSublists(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* new_head = new ListNode(0);
        new_head->next = head;
        ListNode* cur = new_head;
        while(cur != NULL)
        {
            int sum=0;
            while(head != NULL)
            {
                sum += head->val;
                if(sum == 0)
                {
                   cur->next = head->next; 
                }
                head = head->next;
            }
            //What is happening here???
            cur = cur->next;
            if(cur != NULL)
            {
                head = cur->next;
            }
        }
        return new_head->next; 
    }
};
```

Could someone please provide me with an explanation?

Comment: Since it allocates new_head and doesn't delete it, it leaks memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(cur) iterates from the beginning of the list.
for every (cur) start summing the elements after (cur).
when the `sum=0` update `(cur)->next` to point to the first element after this sum. So the first K elements after (cur) with `sum=0` are skipped.

This is done in loop until end of list. In every loop iteration the first K elements with `sum=0` are skipped.

```
// the first K elements starting after (cur) with sum=0 are skipped,
//so (cur) now points to K+1.th element.
            cur = cur->next;
            if(cur != NULL)
            {
                head = cur->next;
            }
```

Time complexity is `O(N*N)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop sums values in consecutive nodes, and also creates a temporary node `cur`.

`cur` jumps two places in the `list` if the `sum` of current consecutive nodes is `0`.
At the end of each loop cycle, the traversing pointer in the `list`, named `head`, gets assigned the value of `cur`.
This way, any pair of consecutive nodes with opposite values gets skipped, and thus not recorded in the `list`.